# Storing multiple integers in a string

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to store 5 integers into a string, but I am having trouble. Here is the code:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            string ans;
            int number;
            int num;
            number = rand() % 9 + 1;
            cout << number << " ";
            num = number;
            to_string(num);
            ans =+ num;
        }
```

Essentially, I would like "ans" to be something along the lines of "12345" but when I run it, it either doesn't show anything or shows 5 boxes with question marks inside of them. Any help?

Comment: You're close, but you want `ans += to_string(num);`.

Comment: Please show real code instead of this obviously fake code that couldn't possibly show anything substantive, because there's not a single line of code here that could display the value of `ans`, that you claim to be seeing. Furthermore, the value of `ans` gets destroyed on every iteration of the loop. The only thing you will get in response to fake code is fake answers.

Comment: Many problems first `to_string(num)` does not do anything it should be `ans+=to_string(num)` also `ans` should be before the if statement.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Obviously I have a display statement that shows ans, I just felt it was not important.

Comment: @JakeFreeman What if statement?

Comment: @zhodges10 *for statement

Comment: @JakeFreeman Oh, I got it, I'm not showing all of the code as there is over a thousand lines currently, I declared it in the beginning of the function, thank you though! Your suggestion worked, I had to tweak it slightly to be ans = ans + to_string(num)

Comment: @zhodges10 _"I'm not showing all of the code as there is over a thousand lines currently,"_ That's why you're required to narrow your code example to a [MCVE], nothing more nothing less.

Comment: `ans =+ num;` is parsed as `ans = (+num);`. The correct operator is `+=`, not `=+`

Comment: @user0042 As I did here.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I see! += works just fine! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @zhodges10 -- *As I did here* -- [Doesn't compile](https://www.ideone.com/DTHMPA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
string ans;
int number;

for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++){ 
    number = rand() % 9 + 1;
    ans += to_string(number);
}
cout << ans;
```

Comment: Actually, what worked for me was ans = ans + to_string(num)! Thank you!

Comment: `ans += to_string(num)` is preferred over `ans = ans + to_string(num)`

Answer (score 0):

`to_string()` returns a string.
You can simply try doing:
`ans += to_string(num);`

Or, better way to write your code for improved readability is to use a temporary string variable instead of an `int num` to store the number.

```
    string temp;
    string ans;
    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
        //string ans;
        int number;
        //int num;
        number = rand() % 9 + 1;
        cout << number << " ";
        //num = number;
        temp = to_string(number);
        ans += temp;
    }
```

You do not want to declare your `string ans` inside the for loop because every time the loop runs, you `ans` will not hold the previous value anymore as it gets declared again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.

- you are declaring `ans` inside the loop, so it is created and destroyed on each loop iteration.  If you want the loop to append 5 numbers to `ans`, you have to declare it outside of the loop instead.
- `std::to_string()` outputs a new `std::string` as its return value. It does not "magically" turn the input value into a string type, like your code is assuming.  You are not appending the returned string to `ans` at all.
- `=+` is not a valid append operator.  It is interpreted as separate operators `=` and `+`.  `std::string` does not have a `=` operator that takes an `int` as input, and does not have a unary `+` operator.  You need to use the `+=` operator instead.

Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string ans;
for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
{
    int number = ...
    ...
    ans += std::to_string(number);
}
// use ans as needed...
```

Alternatively, use `std::ostringstream` instead of `std::to_string()`:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::ostringstream oss;
for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
{
    int number = ...
    ...
    oss << number;
}
std::string ans = oss.str();
// use ans as needed...
```

With that said, you are clearly using C++11 (when `std::to_string()` was introduced) or later, so you should be using a C++ random number generator instead of the one from C, eg:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 9);

for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
{
    int number = dis(gen);
    ...
}
```

Comment: `=+` is valid but parsed as 2 separate operators